# Why do byte spills occur and what do they achieve?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, x86, llvm

What is a byte spill?

When I dump the x86 ASM from an LLVM intermediate representation generated from a C program, there are numerous spills, usually of a 4 byte size. I cannot figure out why they occur and what they achieve.

They seem to "cut" pieces of the stack off, but in an unusual way:

```
## this fragment comes from a C program right before a malloc() call to a struct.
## there are other spills in different circumstances in this same program, so it
## is not related exclusively to malloc()
...
sub ESP, 84
mov EAX, 60
mov DWORD PTR [ESP + 80], 0
mov DWORD PTR [ESP], 60
mov DWORD PTR [ESP + 60], EAX # 4-byte Spill
call malloc
mov ECX, 60
...
```

Answer (score 22):

A register spill is simply what happens when you have more local variables than registers (it's an analogy - really the meaning is that they must be saved to memory).  The instruction is saving the value of EAX, likely because EAX is clobbered by malloc and you don't have another spare register to save it in (and for whatever reason the compiler has decided it needs the constant 60 in the register later).

By the looks of it, the compiler could certainly have omitted `mov DWORD PTR [ESP + 60], EAX` and instead repeated the `mov EAX, 60` where it would otherwise `mov EAX, DWORD PTR [ESP + 60]` or whatever offset it used, because the saved value of EAX cannot be other than 60 at that point.  However, compilation is not guaranteed to be perfectly optimal.

Bear also in mind that after `sub ESP, 84`, the stack size is not adjusted (except by the call instruction which of course pushes the return address).  The following instructions are using ESP as a memory offset, not a destination.

Comment: Or in a debug build compilers spill everything between statements, so everything a statement uses has to get reloaded.  (*[Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)*)